# Firebase Firestore security rules: Using queries in security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am developing a web app on Firebase and Firestore, and here is what I am trying to do:

- Users can upload their own posts, and set its visibility to public or private.
- Any signed in user can see public posts, but only the users who are subscribing to the writer can view private posts. I am trying to write security rules for this.

Here is the database structure:

```
 db.collection('posts').doc({postid})  
 //When a user writes a post, a new document is created. Includes the boolean 'public' field and the 'uid' field, which stores the writer's uid.
 db.collection('subscription').doc({viewer_user_id}) 
 //Once the logged-in user subscribes to another user, a document is created under the user's UID. The doc includes array of the UID of the users the viewer is subscribing.
```

Here are the descriptions of the relevant fields under each of the docs in 'posts' and 'subscription' collections:

```
posts/{postid}: {
  'uid': Writer's uid (String)
  'public': Boolean value to reflect visibility. If false, it is private.
}
subscription/{viewer's uid}: {
   'subscription': Array of uids of the users the viewer is subscribing.
}
```

So, for the private documents, the basic idea is to look at the viewer's document in the subscription collection, get the data, and check whether the uid of the writer is included there. This will require some Javascript codes, but I don't know what the syntax would be in Firestore security rules, or is possible or not there to begin with.

```
 rules_version = '2';
 service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
       function publicOrSubscribed() {
          return request.auth.uid!=null&&(resource.data.public==true|| /*What could be the syntax here??*/)
       }
     match /posts/{postid} {
         allow read: if publicOrSubscribed();
         allow create: if request.auth.uid!=null;
         allow update, delete: if  request.auth.uid==resource.data.userid;
     }
   }
}
```

Any suggestions? If it is not possible in security rules, what might be the workaround? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about the subscription collection and the structure of the documents contained in it. Without knowing the exact fields, it's not possible to write this rule.  Also, you should know that there is documentation for using the contents of other documents using `get()`.  I suggest reading this if you want to solve the problem on your own: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

Comment: Hello @DougStevenson, I edited the question as per your comment. Any suggestions on this? This would require some Javascript operations (e.g. filter method to check if the uid is included in the 'subscription' array), but the documentations don't point there..

Comment: You can check if a string is in a list type field using the `in` operator.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List